# Openlayers 3: Change the vectors layers when the zoom level change

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm a new user of Open-layers 3. I have my web page with layer OSM add by OL3, and I added any vectors layers(markers) by ol.layer.Vector. I need to change the vector layer when the zoom level changes. Please

Comment: I'd recommend better explaining what you want to do. "I need to change the vector layer" is too vague.

Comment: I've two files geojson that represents the vectors layers. I like doing : If the zoom level is < 12 for post up the vectors on the first file geojson and if it's > 13 I liked to post up the vectors of the second file geojson. My wish is similarly of the demo of this link http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/ but it's in Openlayers 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layers have **setVisible()/getVisible()** methods, so you could trigger those on your layers at a particular zoom level.  Zoom can be derived on 'moveend' events, then you can trigger whether a particular layer is visible or not.

Zoom can be gotten from **map.getView().getZoom()** (will return the number that is the zoom), then tell the layer you need to either show or hide accordingly.

Layers are held in an Collection(array) object and can be gotten via a **map.getLayers()** call, then you could choose which one to show/hide.  When I add layers I record the order of them so I can get one directly.

**map.getLayers().item(0)** would return the first layer I added to the layers, (1) the second etc.

Comment: I thank you for your answers, I was able to solve the problem by ol.source.Cluster. Thank you

Comment: **Warning**, I did start using Clusters (see my other questions) recently and found that for large data sets they can be quite slow, so I've switched them off for now.  For low-size data sets they should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can even define directly with the creation of the vector layer the maximun and minimun resolutions.

the class ol.layer.Vector has the options:

- minResolution: The minimum resolution (inclusive) at which this layer will be visible.
- maxResolution: The maximum resolution (exclusive) below which this layer will be visible.

If you don't know the resolution for a map view you can use the method **map.getView().getResolution()** to find out it

Comment: I did try this, but it seems not to work. I have posted [a question about this here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/239044/981).